# Python: list's method similar to dict.get()

Tags: python, algorithm

My problem is to find the consecutive '3's in a list. For example `list('133233313333')` . What makes it difficult is only two adjacent '3's is valid, three or more adjacent '3's are not. So '33' is valid, but triple '3's and '3333' are not valid. I tried the following at first:

```
try:
    if l[i] == '3' and l[i+1] == '3' and l[i+2] != '3' and l[i-1] != '3':
        record_current(i)
except IndexError:
    pass
```

My intention is to ignore the comparison and let it be true if there is an IndexError, but it doesn't work.

If list has a method like dict.get(), which returns None is there's an KeyError, I could write it as `(l[i+2] == None or l[i+2] != '3')`.

If I must finish it now, I would treat the first item and the last two items sperately from the other items. But is there some way to solve this problem elegantly?

Comment: Do you want the indices of all the two consecutive 3's?

Comment: @thefourtheye only the starting 3's index is needed.

Comment: *hint* `zip(l[:-2], l[1:-1], l[2:])` *hint*

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = list('1332333133334433')
>>> for k, g in groupby(enumerate(s), itemgetter(1)):
    if k == '3':
        ind = next(g)[0]
        if sum(1 for _ in g) == 1:
            print ind
...             
1
14
```

Comment: input should be a list, yours uses a string. (though the code is no different)

Comment: That's why I said the code is no different. But for completeness, the OP specified list input.

Answer (score 1):

Count the consecutive 3s !

Keep a counter which is incremented every time you meet a '3' and reset on a non-'3'; compare to 2 before a reset:

```
j= 0
for i in range(len(L)):
    if L[i] == '3':
        j+= 1
    else:
        if j == 2:
            print "Found at", i - j
        j= 0
if j == 2:
    print "Found at", i - j + 1 # Late fix (+ 1)
```

Alternatively, one may find successive runs of '3's and non-'3's. This way, one avoids testing `j == 2` on every non-'3' element, at the expense of one extra loop test for every sequence of 3's:

```
i= 0
while i < len(L):
    # Find the next '3'
    while i < len(L) and L[i] != '3':
        i+= 1
    j= i
    # Find the next non-'3'
    while i < len(L) and L[i] == '3':
        i+= 1
    if i - j == 2:
        print "Found at", j
```

Comment: Please restore it to your last version of answer. I like that. And this one doesn't give the right result. But you missed '+j', it should be `while i + j < len(L) and L[i+j] == '3':`. Thank you!

Comment: I have added a variant in the same vein as the old one, with a better indexing scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check for a certain Grammar. For this, you can implement a [Deterministic Finite Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (or DFA).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general solution for finding two consecutive letters that are the same:

```py
def find_two_consecutive(my_str):
prev_letter = None
count = 1
for index, current_letter in enumerate(my_str):
    if current_letter == prev_letter:
        count += 1
    else:
        if count == 2:
            print("Starting at index: %d" % (index - 2))
        count = 1
        prev_letter = current_letter

if count == 2:
    print("Starting at index: %d" % (index - 2))
```

Comment: You are missing the final instance, if any; and there is no need to perform the assignment prev_letter = current_letter in case current_letter == prev_letter

Comment: You are right @YvesDaoust, thanks. I should have tested for edge cases. Thanks for the heads up, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses regular expressions:

```
import re
m = re.finditer('(?<!3)3{2}(?!3)', '1332333133334433')
for x in m:
    print x.span()[0]
```

The regular expression finds all matches for two successive threes, as long as they are not followed by or preceeded by a 3. The output is:

```
1
14
```

You can substitute any character for the '3' in the regular expression, to search for that letter instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = "1332333133334433"
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = []
for char, grp in groupby(enumerate(data), itemgetter(1)):
    groups = list(grp)
    if char == "3" and len(groups) == 2:
        result.append(groups[0][0])
print result
```

**Output**

```
[1, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list really only contains one-letter elements you should use the `re` module:

```
import re

chars = list('133233313333433')
numberstr = ''.join(chars)

for match in re.finditer('(?<!3)33(?!3)', numberstr):
    print(match.start())
```

Result:

```
1
13
```

The pattern `(?<!3)33(?!3)` means: find two consecutive 3s that are neither preceded nor followed by a 3.

The documentation can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html).

Oh, and this:

```
chars = list('133233313333433')
numberstr = ''.join(chars)
```

should probably be just:

```
numberstr = '133233313333433'
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns `True` if '333' in the list

```
>>> l = "1332333133334433"
>>> any([(i[:3]=='333' and i[3] != '3') for i in map("".join,zip(l[:],l[1:],l[2:],l[3:]))])
True
```

you can see that:

```
>>> map("".join,zip(l[:],l[1:],l[2:],l[3:]))
['1332', '3323', '3233', '2333', '3331', '3313', '3133', '1333', '3333', '3334', '3344', '3443', '4433']
```

Comment: This returns True in the case `l` is `3333` which the original author does not want.